# Best way to retrieve all the table records in Apache Gora 0.5

Tags: apache, hbase, gora

I know about

```
 query.setStartKey(startKey);
 query.setEndKey(endKey);
```

Isn't there something similar to

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE;
```

in Apache Gora while creating queries, that would return me all the result set.

**EDIT***
I executed the program without setting anything. But still, the result set is null.

```
 Query<String, Obj> query = store.newQuery();
 Result<String, Obj> result= query.execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't set the start nor the end key, it will retrieve all the table like the select you talk about -at least with HBase-.

Comment: `Query<String, Obj>` ? What is your DataStore generics parameters? What are your machine specs? What value do you have as `gora.hbasestore.scanner.caching` in `gora.properties`? LOG level? Any log? Local, pseudodistributed, distributed? Are you sure there is data (checked with hbase shell)? I ask many questions because it should work as you did.

Comment: Alfonso Thank you very much. I checked the hadoop.log. During avro schema creation I made a mistake. I had written "default": "null" instead of "default": null. There was type mismatch in schema creation. I was confident about my question because data was injecting in to the hbase and I was annoyed by getting no results. Thanks, I solved my problem.